Falconer's Distance Conjecture: Why is the boundary set to n/2?
Falconer's distance conjecture states that if a compact Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has (Hausdorff) dimension greater than $\frac{n}{2}$, then its distance set
$$ \mathcal{D}(A) := \{|x - y|: x,y \in A \}$$
has positive Lebesgue measure. I know that this conjecture is seen as a "continuous analogue" of a similar conjecture from Erdős (where there is a limit $\frac 2 n$ being closely related to $\frac n 2$). Furthermore, in M. Burak Erdogan's Falconer's Distance Set Conjecture (2004) he writes: in [7], Falconer gave an example showing that $\frac{d}{2}$ in the conjecture is optimal, where [7] refers to the paper On the Hausdorff dimension of distance sets by Falconer, which I haven't got access to, and I was wondering whether / how the counterexamples were for sets $A$ with Hausdorff dimension $1 < \mathrm{dim} A < \frac n2$.
